# Send and receive a post variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, get

I'm trying to send a post variable to the url which I'm redirecting to.

I'm currently using the Get method and sending it like this:

```
// Redirect to page with url parameter (GET)
Response.Redirect("web pages/livestream.aspx?address="+ ((Hardwarerecorders.Device)devices[arrayIndex]).streamAddress);
```

And retrieving it like this:

```
// Get the url parameter here
string address = Request.QueryString["address"];
```

How do I convert my code to use the POST method?

**B.T.W.**, I don't want to use a form to send the post variable.

Comment: Try to use webclient class and make request.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri Can you please give me an example

Comment: Please see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **HttpClient**:

To send POST query:

```
using System.Net.Http;

public string sendPostRequest(string URI, dynamic content)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yourBaseAddress");

        var valuesAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(valuesAsJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = client.PostAsync(URI, contentPost).Result;
        return result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

Where '***client.PostAsync(URI, contentPost)***' is where the content is being sent to the other website.

On the other website, an API Controller needs to be established to receive the result, something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("yourURI")]
    public void receivePost([FromBody]dynamic myObject)
    {
        //..
    }
```

However, you might also want to look into using a 307 re-direct, especially if this is a temporary solution.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99966

Comment: Thanks! But how do I sent it? And when the browser arrived at the redirected page, how do I retrieve the post content?

Comment: I misunderstood slightly, the above method simply sends from one location and receives the result back. Updating now.

Comment: Note that 'myObject' can be of any type; string, array, etc. Ideally if you know the type beforehand, its better to declare it.

Comment: Does this only work if the second website is opened in another tab?

Comment: Well not necessarily open, but there needs to be another instance of it running. So if you're testing locally it needs to be running on some server such as IIS or Apache.

Comment: No :( It says: "The type or namespace 'HttpClient' could not be found".. I've tried to import the namespace 'System.Net.Http', but that can't find Http.. Any solution for this?

Comment: Install [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) nuget package, then add a reference to `System.Net.Assembly`

Comment: Also I can't comment on the other answer by A Biswas, but Get and Post do not work like that! You do not POST from one end and GET it from another, they are two separate protocols! A GET method still sends a request, it just does not contain a body with content in it.

Comment: I suppose, I have to add the reference `System.Net.Http`? If so, it already was added..

Comment: Are you adding reference to the dll by right clicking on the "references" tab and selecting "Add Reference..." ?

Comment: Yes, if this is the right way.. https://gyazo.com/4389a17b73f4cfa1ee13b40c5bac2bf1.png

Comment: And did you install it in the correct project within the solution? The method described in the link is the correct way of referencing HttpClient so you must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Okay, I've tried it in a class with `using System.Net.Http;` and that just works perfect. The only thing is that I want to use it in ASP.Net (while using the language C#), so I have to use `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Http" %>`, but when using that, it won't work..

Comment: Maybe we can discuss about this problem in this chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106372/send-an-receive-a-post-variable

Comment: I don't have enough stack overflow points yet to chat :( Send me your email or something on the chat (I can still see messages you write), and I'll message you

Comment: Hmm how many points do you need? I can give you 15 points for accepting the answer?

Comment: Well if you think the answer is helpful you could! I would be grateful haha. I should have enough then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106389/discussion-between-andrew-cachia-and-m-zeinstra).

Comment: I'm in the chat again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

POST

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "thing1", "hello" },
       { "thing2", "world" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

GET

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var responseString = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
}
```

My Personal Choice is Restsharp it's fast but for basic operations you can use this

Comment: @A But one thing I don't understand.. How do I redirect to the given page with the given post variables and retreive them IN the redirected page?

Comment: Just use the "get" code in the page you want the data to be fetched , your data will be saved in the responseString

Comment: It says: "The type or namespace 'HttpClient' could not be found".. I've tried to import the namespace 'System.Net.Http', but that can't find Http.. Any solution for this?

Comment: Add this `using System.Net.Http;`